# Using image with Kotlin and React

Tags: xml, reactjs, image, kotlin

I created this webpage with create-react-kotlin-app. The xml is different than I'm used to and I'm really struggling using a logo that is in the same directory as index.kt. How can I fix this?

```
package index

import react.dom.*
import kotlin.browser.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val rootDiv = document.getElementById("root")

    render(rootDiv) {
        img(src="./logo.jpg"){}
    }
}
```

Comment: Haven't worked on create-react-kotlin-app recently, but try moving your image in your `src/resources` folder. (That is even if you have one)

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work. I didn't have the resources folder, but I created it. Tried src="logo.jpg", src="./resources/logo.jpg" and src="./../resources/logo.jpg" (index.kt is inside folder inside src folder). I also tried moving index.kt out so it's just under the source folder, but couldn't get it to work that way either.

Comment: try `img(src=require("./logo.jpg")){}` and reference your image correctly

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a solution simply by taking a look at the create-react-kotlin-app default content, a little awkward.

```
package index

import react.dom.*
import kotlin.browser.*

@JsModule("src/resources/logo.jpg")
external val logo: dynamic

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val rootDiv = document.getElementById("root")

    render(rootDiv) {
        img(src = logo){}
    }
}
```

Unnecessarily cumbersome if you ask me.