# How to reference image resource in kotlin/JS

Tags: javascript, image, kotlin, kotlin-js

I try to reference an image resource from react kotlin app.

welcome.kt under src/main/kotlin:

```
import react.dom.img

@JsModule("./logo.svg")
@JsNonModule
external val logo: dynamic

@JsExport
class Welcome : RComponent<RProps, RState>() {

    override fun RBuilder.render() {
        img {
            attrs {
                src = logo
            }
        }
    }
}
```

logo.svg was saved under src/main/resources

Building application ends in

```
Module './logo.svg' not found
```

Application was created with "React Application" template in IntelliJ Idea 2020.3.2

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54937081/using-image-with-kotlin-and-react